# Set/show the selected/saved value(from database) to a select box for editing purposes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value I have saved to database and show it in a select box.
The items in the select box is populated from the database.

```
<select id="sel2" name="sel2">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <?php 
        require("connection.php");

        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT field FROM table");
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value='".$row['field']."'>'".$row['field']."'</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Now, when I try to do this,

```
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    var x = "field1";
    $('#sel2').val(x);
});
```

the value of x do not appear in the select box. But when the items are not fetch from the database like,

```
<select id="sel2" name="sel2">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="field1">field1</option>
    <option value="field2">field2</option>
    <option value="field3">field3</option>
</select>
```

the jquery works.

I don't know what I am missing here. Could you help me on this. How to set the selected value(came from database that was chosen before) of a Select box when the items were populated from the database?

I am fetching the items of select box from the database because there are too many of them. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the jquery code is being executed right BEFORE the fields are fetched from the database. Thus the statement `$('#sel2').val(x);` can't set the value `x` because at that time, the `x` field doesn't exist in the select dropdown.

If unsure, try to use a timeout in the jquery click function just to check if whatever I have said is true or not.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hi Harshil, I got the insights, but it doesn't seem to work. setTimeout(function(){ $('#sel2').val(x); }); inside the click function. Well, the actual value of x will be coming from the returned data of an ajax call.

Comment: i mean setTimeout(function(){ $('#sel2').val(x); }, 2000); It didn't work for me.

Comment: Put the jquery code in the callback of the ajax call function

Comment: Hey bro. I found the problem. I'm using select2.js. That's why the code didn't worked out. Idk why. I guess I'm not gonna use it for now. But anyway, thanks, your idea works when i removed the link to select2.js. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and seems like you have an extra single quotation marks

```
echo "<option value='".$row['field']."'>".$row['field']."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    var x = 'field1';
    $("#sel2").val(x);
    $("#sel2").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Comment: Hi, actually the value of x here will be coming from the returned data of an ajax call. Where should I put the .trigger? And what is "chosen:updated"? Thanks.

Comment: jQuery.ajax({            
 success: function(data) {
  // HERE YOU HAVE TO DO THAT
 }
});